# Batch file: Extracting substring from input parameter to use in IF statement

Tags: batch-file, parameters, substring, if-statement

This is a very basic example of what I am trying to implement in a more complex batch file. I would like to extract a substring from an input parameter (`%1`) and branch based on if the substring was found or not.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

SET _testvariable=%1
SET _testvariable=%_testvariable:~4,3%

ECHO %_testvariable%

IF %_testvariable%=act CALL :SOME
IF NOT %_testvariable%=act CALL :ACTION

:SOME
ECHO Substring found
GOTO :END

:ACTION
ECHO Substring not found
GOTO :END
ENDLOCAL

:END
```

---

This is what my output looks like:

```
C:\>test someaction

act

=act was unexpected at this time.
```

---

If possible I would like to turn this in to a IF/ELSE statement and evaluate directly from `%1`. However I have not had success with either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `IF` statements, replace `=` with `==`.

I think you also want to replace your `CALL` statements with `GOTO`.

Here is your code, but using `IF/ELSE` instead of two `IF` statements.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL enableextensions enabledelayedexpansion

SET _testvariable=%1
SET _testvariable=%_testvariable:~4,3%

ECHO %_testvariable%

IF %_testvariable%==act (
  GOTO :SOME
) ELSE (
  GOTO :ACTION
)

:SOME
ECHO Substring found
GOTO :END

:ACTION
ECHO Substring not found
GOTO :END

:END

ENDLOCAL
```

Comment: It was the == that seemed to have fixed it. My original batch file where I was having the issues was ~300+ lines and I overlooked the minor detail.

Thanks for being my extra set of eyes.

Comment: You are welcome. Batch files can be tricky to debug sometimes.